# French horn - Getting higher register

Tags: brass, instrument-range, french-horn

Does anyone know some good **techniques or practises** I can do to **improve my high range** on the horn relatively quick (like 2 months quick)? It can be for brass and doesn't have to be specific for horn- though preferred.

I changed my embouchure at around March this year but I can only play the F above the stave somewhat comfortably without pushing. My grade requires me to play up to the C which is 4 notes above that, but right now even playing the A will do.

**All recommendations/suggestions highly appreciated!!**

Comment: From personal experience: borrow or rent a trumpet, trombone, or other larger bore / larger mouthpiece brass instrument. Just play long tones one it; you don't need to actually learn to play. But the greater demands on your breath, power, and embouchure will assist with your horn playing. Also [this post about trumpet range](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/104283/70803) might help.

Comment: @Aaron I have some odd personal experience that may support this. I studied trombone for my Bachelor of Music degree, and whenever I picked up a french horn I had zero difficulty belting out concert F5s and the like. I would play up to the same range on trombone, but the smaller mouthpiece of the french horn felt like a cheat code ;-)

Comment: Fortunately my sister plays trumpet and I'll have a go at that! And thank you for the post, it's very helpful.

Comment: @NReilingh I thought that a smaller mouthpiece was more difficult to get high notes and rather bigger mouthpieces such as trumpet mouth pieces were easier.

Comment: I’m not sure what metric you’re using for small/large in that case. If you compare, say, tuba and trumpet, the tuba mouthpiece is much larger, and if you buzz on the mouthpiece alone, the “default” pitch on the trumpet mouthpiece will be much higher than the tuba.

Comment: Recently, you requested access to the Basic Mathematics chat-room. Did you have a mathematics question? And I would like to know, why did you hide your accounts on Music SE and Korean SE?

Comment: Hi :) Sorry about that! I was just interested in a question that was being asked. And what does it mean for an account to be hidden? I'm new here and I might've accidentally done something I didn't intend to do haha!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lip slurs, scales and arpeggios up to the required range (and a little above it).  Also concoct some exercises with less predictable notes.   I made a breakthrough into my trombone's upper range (many years ago) with exercises like this.  Make sure air, not pressure, is getting you there!

WHAT exercises you use are less important than doing LOTS of playing up there!

[image]